# using multiple Proxy

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am creating threaded website scraper that uses watin .It will search google for my entered string in text box , 
i want that each thread uses different proxy and they run at same time.is it possible to use proxies without changing registry.i have done with registry and works prefect or any sugesstion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use WebRequest, there is a proxy property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.proxy.aspx

Comment: can we make application that searches google for a word and navigates to various pages?
Using Httpwebresponse or request

Comment: You should create another question for this.